# No se registra variable con TextInput Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

nuevamente. Estaba programando con kivy y al registrar un valor en una variable mediante TextInput, al intentar imprimirla, me dice que no está declarada. Gracias de antemano:

Adjunto código .py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy

kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyGrid(Widget):

    tipo_aceite = ObjectProperty(None)

    aceite = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        tipo_aceite="Oliva"
        print("El tipo de aceite es: ",tipo_aceite, "Y la cantidad: ",aceite)


class SoapApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SoapApp().run()
```

Y el .kv:

```
<MyGrid>
    aceite: aceite
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: "Cantidad de aceite: "
            TextInput:
                id: aceite
                multiline:False
        Button:
            text:"Oliva"
            on_press:root.btn()
        Label:
            text:"La cantidad de aceite es: "+str(aceite)
```

Y el mensaje de error:

```
 File "./Soap.py", line 20, in btn
     print("El tipo de aceite es: ",tipo_aceite, "Y la cantidad: ",aceite)
 NameError: name 'aceite' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

El error básico está en el `kv`, en las líneas:

- **`aceite: aceite`**

  Ésto enlaza la property con el `Entry` (id `aceite`), pero con la instancia del widget. Debes enlazar con la property text del mismo:

  ```
  aceite: aceite.text
  ```
- **`text:"La cantidad de aceite es: "+str(aceite)`**

  lo mismo, aceite es la intancia del Entry con id aceite, no la property, debe ser:

  ```
  text:"La cantidad de aceite es: "+str(root.aceite) # Contenido de la property
  ```

  o:

  ```
  text:"La cantidad de aceite es: " + str(aceite.text) # Contenido del Entry
  ```

Te aconsejo no dar la misma id al `Entry` que el nombre de la propiedad, los nombres de las variables cuanto más descriptivos mejor, al final se agradece el esfuerzo de escribir unas letras más si la variable solo con su nombre nos indica que es.

**`main.py`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyGrid(Widget):

    tipo_aceite = ObjectProperty()
    cantidad_aceite = ObjectProperty(0)

    def btn(self):
        self.tipo_aceite = "Oliva"
        print((f"El tipo de aceite es: {self.tipo_aceite} " 
               f"Y la cantidad: {self.cantidad_aceite}")
              )

class SoapApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SoapApp().run()
```

**`soap.kv`**

```
<MyGrid>
    cantidad_aceite: cant_aceite_entry.text
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: "Cantidad de aceite: "
            TextInput:
                id: cant_aceite_entry
                multiline:False
        Button:
            text:"Oliva"
            on_press:root.btn()
        Label:
            text: "La cantidad de aceite: " + root.cantidad_aceite if root.cantidad_aceite else ""
```

Comment: Gracias! De nuevo, he descubierto que aún no se me desbloquean los votos, así que me sabe mal no poder hacer nada aún.

Comment: Hola Brian, para que poder votar positivo necesitas 15 puntos de reputación mínimos y 125 para negativo ([Privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)), lo que si puedes hacer es considerar aceptar aquellas respuestas a tus preguntas que consideres que mejor responden a tu problema, si la hay. Para saber cómo puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089), de paso recibes algunos puntos también. Un saludo.